# How to know when docker image was pull in my docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

I want to know when I pulled a certain image when you run `docker images`. The Created field appears but it tells when this image was created not when the image was pulled into my system.
Is there any way I can know when was this image pulled into my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker image ls | grep <image-name>  // find image id (sha256 value)
eg :- consul   0.9.2  9bf1618f4e63        3 years ago         51.7MB

ls -lrth /var/lib/docker/image/<GRAPH DRIVER>/imagedb/content/sha256 | grep <image-id>
eg:- ls -lrth /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/ | grep 9bf1618f4e63
```